# Multiple handle change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am working on project which contains more than 200 input fields for list.is it possible to manage them with single state input

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Item from "../Components/Item";

const initialState={
  input:''
}

const List = () => {
  const [values,setValues]=useState(initialState)

  const handleChange=(e)=>{
    setValues({
      ...values,[e.target.name]:e.target.value
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="listhead">
        <h3 className="text-center">Price List-2022</h3>
        <table className="table table-bordered border-dark table-hover text-center">
          <thead className="bg-success text-white table-bordered border-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>S.No</th>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
              <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <Item
            product="bomb"
            name="input"
            price="50"
            value={values.input}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
          <Item
            product="chakkar"
            name="input"
            price="100"
            value={values.input}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default List;
```

child element

```
const Item = ({name,product,price,value,handleChange}) => {
    return (
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>{product}</th>
        <th>{price}</th>
        <th className="w-25">
          <input
            name={name}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type='number'
          />
        </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  );
};
export default Item;
```

with this code if i enter values in input fields all other input fields reads the same value. if i need to create 200 input field with data, what are the ways to do that?

Comment: where do you loop the list?

Comment: sorry actually i forgot to mention product name in item.I directly pass the values from list to item.

Comment: question updated

Comment: 1. Your two inputs have the same name, thus they update the same field in the state.
2. Dealing with large forms can be a mess, and in this case I would be a bit worried about rerenders. onChange and state updates alot.
I am using https://react-hook-form.com/ which can relieve you from the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass all values to item
like this :

```
 <Item
        name="input"
        price="50"
        value={values}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
```

and in Item component set props of input like this :

```
        <input
            name={name}
            value={values[name]}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type='number'
          />
```

Comment: and for initialState it's better to set only {} as value

Comment: oh my god.. it works. thanks bro.  :). can you please explain that

Comment: You did most of it's parts and I just corrected that ,
forexample, when you change value of 'bomb' in your handleChange function will update state in this way {bomb:e.target.value}

so clearly for updating input value we need to use values.bomb and now I know values of state has this object {bomb:'some value ' } and I have key of object (it's input name ) so I just need to use values[name] as value of input

Comment: please let me know, if needs more explanation

Comment: my pleasure, if my answer is what your were looking for please mark it as the answer

Answer (score -1):

Your inputs have the same `name`, if you want to set the state for the different inputs you'll need a unique identifier.

This way you can use the `e.target.name` as a key in your state object.

```html
<Item
  product="Something"
  name={"unique identifier"}
  price="50"
  value={values["unique identifier"]}
  handleChange={handleChange}
/>
```

A good practice is also to use the callback function with the useState to make sure you have the most recent values.

```js
setValues((prevValues) => {
  return {
    ...prevValues,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  };
});
``
```